# AVSpeechUtterance as UILocalNotification sound

Tags: ios, ios7, background, uilocalnotification, avspeechsynthesizer

Hello and thanks for reading this!

In the foreground my app plays an iOS7 `AVSpeechUtterance` for a timed event.  In the background I pass a  a .wav file name to a `soundName` property of `UILocalNotification`. This all works.

Is there a way to use `AVSpeechUtterance` as the sound of a `UILocalnotification`? I would like the same sythesis in the foreground as the background.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Create this method in the `appdelegate.m` file. 
Dont forget to import AVFoundation/AVSpeechSynthesis.h in Appdelegate.h

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification
{
    UIApplicationState state = [application applicationState];
    if (state == UIApplicationStateActive) {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Reminder"
                                                        message:notification.alertBody
                                                       delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                              otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
    }
    AVSpeechUtterance *utterance = [AVSpeechUtterance
                                    speechUtteranceWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",notification.alertBody]];
    AVSpeechSynthesizer *synth = [[AVSpeechSynthesizer alloc] init];
    utterance.volume = 10;
    utterance.rate = 0.2;
    utterance.pitchMultiplier = 1;
    [synth speakUtterance:utterance];

    // Request to reload table view data
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"reloadData" object:self];

    // Set icon badge number to zero
    application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;
}
```